# After uploading apk on playstore, 0 devices in Supported Devices

Tags: android

After uploading apk on playstore, 0 devices in Supported Devices.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svdVi.jpg)

[manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzRbP.png)

Comment: what is  minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Comment: post your gradle

Comment: There is not enough information about your app. Post your gradle file and manifest.

Comment: minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25

Answer (score 0):

first you should have to publish apk successfully.. with content rating and testing mode

Comment: I have published apk successfully.. with content rating and testing mod

Comment: give me your app link

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orthotain.healthystart

Comment: but it shows the supported devices instantly as I upload the apk.

Comment: now check your publisher account you will see number of supported device

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Actually it was not related to time publishing on play store. I rebuilt the app and published again, removing below lines from manifest.

<compatible-screens>
        
    </compatible-screens>

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was not related to time publishing on play store. I rebuilt the app and published again, removing below lines from manifest.